# Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC with Intent.setDataAndType returns no result

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an audio file which I want device default app or any other installed apps that can handle audio files play this audio. So I have this:

```
private void playMedia(String mediaPath) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(mediaPath);
        String mimetype = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(mediaPath), mimetype);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If I don't set `setDataAndType` two of my players will respond,

But if I set `setDataAndType`:

> ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC] dat=/storage/emulated/0/Audio.mp3 typ=audio/mpeg

The device I'm working on(API 24) has a few players like `mxPlayer,playerPro,shareIt Music,google play music,default player ...`

Am I doing something wrong here?

**UPDATE (Final Answer)**

As the accepted answer suggested I tried with file so the working code is:

```
private void playMedia() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(inPath);
        String mimetype = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        String type = null;
        try {
            type = mimetype.split("/")[0].toLowerCase().trim();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (type==null)
            type="*";
        File file = new File(inPath);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type+"/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, FilenameUtils.getBaseName(inPath)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this：

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(mediaPath);
String mimetype = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File audioFile = new File(sdcard.getPath() + "/Music/goodmorningandroid.mp3"); 
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(audioFile), mimetype); //notice this line
```

**Edited**:
    Permissions for read and write sdcard are needed.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, I tried with file, still same exception.

Comment: But, I tried fromFile with `ACTION_VIEW` intent, not `CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC`. I got my desired result, Thank's again